# Set UICulture to Html.EditorFor method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my application the MVC Culture is set to "en-US" and UICulture is set to "nl-NL".
I have a view which renders a model containing a Datetime object.
If I render it like this:

```
Html.EditorFor(x => x.ForFilter.FromDate)
```

it will be shown in in the en-US culture format. So In order to show the date in the Dutch format I had to do this:

```
var shortDatePattern = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ForFilter.FromDate, new {Value = Model.ForFilter.FromDate.ToString(shortDatePattern) })
```

I am aware of the existence of the `DisplayFormat` attribute which I can use for the `DateTime` fields, but that is not a solution because the `UICulture` is determined at runtime.

So, is there a more elegant solution of telling the `EditorFor` and `TextboxFor` methods to use the `UICulture` instead of Culture?

Comment: Microsoft seem to of forgotten that non-Us format dates exist in MVC

Comment: Yes, well I have another example to give. When executing hand written sql queries with nhibernate via Session.CreateSQLQuery() and then List() method you get just a raw object. Then if you try to do something like Convert.ToDateTime(x[1]); where x is an object array from the raw object you get into trouble if the format of the date returned from whatever SQL server you use does not match the expected format for the application culture.  This is yet another reason why the application culture cannot be always the same as the UICulture.

Answer (score 0):

```
Model.ForFilter.FromDate.ToString("d", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture)
```

would be more elegant than what you currently have IMHO.

But if you want dates (and presumably numbers) formatted in nl-NL culture, why not set `CurrentCulture` to nl-NL?

For example, [in web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
<globalization culture="nl-NL" uiCulture="nl-NL" />
```

Comment: Because the culture is determined at runtime. So for user X the culture must be Dutch but for some other user it must be German for example. So I am keeping the application culture en-US and the UICulture is changed in order to have all resources/dates/numbers formatted as per user culture.

Comment: @user1980412 - so why don't you simply set CurrentCulture to the user-specific culture?

Comment: because there is some code that relies on the en-US culture to build some SQL queries. For example when making an insert/update and the value being updated is a float that should be at the SQL level represented as 4.12, I would get 4,12 if I set the Culture to nl-NL. If I should rely on the culture of the application also for the UI, then I also don't see the point of having a UICulture property anymore. Further more in the ASP.NET Web Forms, if I remember correctly, the UICulture is taken into account when setting some value to a label on the form for example.

Comment: @user1980412 - then you should be using parametrized queries.  But if you want to generate culture-independent strings, whether for an SQL query or anything else, you should use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.

Comment: I agree with you on using parametrized queries. It just doesn't feel right for me that, when using Resources for example, MVC does take the UICulture into account showing thus the correct string for the specified resource key and that this does not happen in case of ModelBinding or when trying to do something like I describe above. The lesson I learn from this discussion is that I have to make sure that the system in general works whatever the culture and forget about the UICulture in MVC.